# Move UITableView cell contents (subviews) in a custom Nib based table cell class in response to engaging edit mode and showing a reorder control

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5

I have a custom table cell, right now, it's all Nib based. When I go into editing mode, the editing accessory view makes room for the reorder control, by animating to the left.

However, a custom view I have in my table cell, stays put. It seems that one's own custom UIView's inside the cell, are left as is. I'm so used to seeing table cell content shift, I almost thought this was automagically handled (maybe it is, and I'm not hooking into that facility)?

To compensate, I'm just applying a transform on my custom subview when entering/exiting editing mode on the table cell. It all works, but I wonder if I'm doing this the best way I can.

Eventually, I'll likely move to pure drawRect: cells, but that aside, in a purely Nib based table cell construction, what's the best practice for doing these adjustments? A conditional set of placements in layoutSubviews?

Here's my override of the editing method on my custom table cell class, and an image of the view ("Stats Bank View") I'm looking to slide in.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    CGAffineTransform transformToApply = (self.isEditing ? 
        CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-38, 0) : CGAffineTransformIdentity);

    RPExerciseSetTableCellBase *capturedSelf = self;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:(animated ? 0.25f : 0.0f) 
                          delay:0.0f 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                     animations:^{
                         capturedSelf.middleStatsBackgroundImageView.transform = 
                            transformToApply;
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         // Nothing to do as yet.
                     }];
}
```

And here's how the layout in the Nib looks:

[image: Custom Table Cell Nib with custom subview selected I wish to reposition when editing reorder control appears]

**In Summary, my question:** For pure Nib based cells, what's the best practice technique (and why) for re-arranging custom interior subviews of the cell in response to the reordering control appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your changes in `-layoutSubviews` based on whether the table is editing or not. Any changes made here are automatically animated for you.